# Simple Framework: Eliminating unwanted white space in serialized XML

Tags: java, whitespace, simple-framework

**Question**:

> How to eliminate unnecessary white space characters from the serialized XML while using Simple framework?

**Details:**

Let's consider [this](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#start) very basic example from the Simple framework website. The XML output is:

```
<example index="123">
   <text>Example message</text>
</example>
```

How do I instruct the serializer to output this instead?

`<example index="123"><text>Example message</text></example>`

I checked the `org.simpleframework.xml.stream.Style` interface, but it only seems to be able to work on individual element and attribute *names* and not the content.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Tichodroma Efficiency and Bandwidth. I have a large XML as response to my REST API. The tags and content are ... sparse. The newlines take up a noticeable chunk of the response body. I figure that eliminating the unneeded characters will not only lower the data transferred over the wire; it will also improve parsing efficiency on the client side. I cannot use GZip encoding since my API also serves a constrained embedded device which does not have gunzip capability.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `Format` class for this:

**Usage:**

```
final Format format = new Format(0);

Serializer ser = new Persister(format);
ser.write(new Example(123, "Example message"), new File("out.xml"));
```

---

Assuming that your `Example` class looks something like this:

```
@Root
public class Example
{
    @Attribute(name="index", required=true)
    private int index;
    @Element(name="text", required=true)
    private String text;


    public Example(int index, String text)
    {
        this.index = index;
        this.text = text;
    }


    // ...

}
```

You'll get the following XML (File `out.xml`) with the `Serializer` code from above:

```
<example index="123"><text>Example message</text></example>
```

Comment: Thanks. That works like a charm. I was always under the assumption that a `0` passed to `indent` argument to the `Format` object would still introduce a new line, but all the elements would be left-aligned!